# share table creation and drop between many tests

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have some tests executing some sql queries on a table `people`. I want to create this table only once, execute the tests, and then drop the table.

For the moment, the version I wrote does the creation and drop for each test. Here is my code:

```scala
def withTable(testCode: Unit => Any): Any = {
    sparkSession.sql("CREATE TABLE people(id INT, name STRING, age BYTE) USING PARQUET")
    try {
      testCode
    } finally {
      sparkSession.sql("DROP TABLE people")
    }
}


"global test" when {
  "test1" should {
    "do something" in withTable { _ =>
      spark.sql(query1) shouldBe ...
    }
  }

  "test2" should {
    "do something" in withTable { _ =>
      spark.sql(query2) shouldBe ...
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do the creation and drop only once ?

Comment: http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.1/org/scalatest/BeforeAndAfterAll.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank's ! That's what I was looking for